# UWP - ListView Scrolling - won't stay at scrolled position

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I have a `ListView` with grouping. Everything works fine except scrolling. If I want to scroll down the `ListView` then after releasing the `ListView` goes back on the beginning. I have tried to set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` to `Enabled` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto`. But no success.

XAML code:

```
<PivotItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >    
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox"
                     PlaceholderText="Search ... "
                     TextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged"/>

        <ListView x:Name="ContactsListView"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactsTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsViewSource.View}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

                  <ListView.GroupStyle>
                     <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupingItem">
                              <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}"
                                         Foreground="Blue"
                                         Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                     </GroupStyle>
                  </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</PivotItem>
```

Could you give me some hint? Because I have searched the net but without any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to replace `StackPanel` with `Grid` in `PivotItem`.

```
<PivotItem>
    <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="50" />
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox"
                     PlaceholderText="Search ... "
                     TextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged"
                     Grid.Row="0"/>

        <ListView x:Name="ContactsListView"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactsTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsViewSource.View}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  Grid.Row="1" >

                  <ListView.GroupStyle>
                     <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupingItem">
                              <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}"
                                         Foreground="Blue"
                                         Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                     </GroupStyle>
                  </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
   </Grid>
</PivotItem>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I would not have figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to scroll down the ListView then after releasing the ListView goes back on the beginning

You can listen to the Scroll event of the vertical ScrollBar, and use the ScrollViewer to pragmatically adjust the ScrollBar position, when it's at the bottom.

```
        var scrollViewer = GetDescendants(ContactsListView).OfType<ScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault();
        var verticalScrollbar = GetDescendants(scrollViewer).OfType<ScrollBar>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical);
        verticalScrollbar.Scroll += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.ScrollEventType != ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
                return;

            if (e.NewValue >= verticalScrollbar.Maximum)
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0); // Scroll to the top
        };
```

Below is the helper class you can use to navigate the ListView visual tree to find the ScrollViewer and the Vertical ScrollBar.

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetDescendants(DependencyObject start)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(start);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(start, i);
            yield return child;
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var parent = queue.Dequeue();
            var count2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

            for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                yield return child;
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
    }
```